# <img> tag inside an <a> tag works only in IE

Tags: html, cross-browser, anchor, image

I'm trying to make a logo image, which should work as a hyperlink and redirect the user to the  Home Page when clicked.

```
<a class="fleft block" href="../../Pages/HomePage.aspx">
    <img class="logo" src="../../Images/logo.gif" alt="Logo" /></a>
```

This code works fine in IE, it behaves as expected. However the image is not clickable in FireFox, Chrome, Opera and Safari.

Any ideas why?
Thanks, Anton

EDIT: 
Alright guys, thanks for the answers. I've removed my css classes (float: left and display: block) and now it's working

Comment: Can you set up a demo on jsfiddle.net ? Thanks.

Comment: You must have something else going on... I can't see a problem. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Anton Looks fine should work.If possible create a fiddle.

Comment: Your code is workin on my computer with firefox.

Comment: Inspect the Element in Chrome or Firefox and see if it has any Inherited Styles?

Comment: Hmm I've made an example in jsfiddle.net, but it seems that it's working.

Comment: Alright guys, thanks for the answers. I've removed my css classes (float: left and display: block) and now it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you float the link ?
if you do so it will not encapsulate the entire image. if this is the case, you might want to give your link a widht and height in css.

```
.fleft.block{
  width: "your image width";
  height: "your image height";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. If you want to change the cursor over image, try this in your CSS;

```
.logo{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```